# I'm having trouble reading in lines from a text file?

Tags: c++, string

I want to read in a line from a text file, store the line in an array of strings to later display the line numbers a word can be found on, and also break down the line into words for marking how many times unique words come up. I have successfully been able to break down the lines word by word and mark the frequency in which they appear but I'm struggling with storing the line in an array of strings so that I can use it later.

```
void get_word(istream& in_stream, string& w,
              list<string> &wordlist, int& lineCount, string *line)
{

  string t;
  getline(in_stream,t);

  for (int j=0; t[j]; j++)
    t[j] = tolower(t[j]);

  line = &t;
  istringstream iss(t);
  string word;
  while(iss >> word) 
  {
    insert_word(word, wordlist);
  }

}
```

So far this is what I have and no matter what I try to do with the line where I try to assign the string "t" to the "line" array that's being pointed to it doesn't put anything in the array, I think I'm just completely missing something.
line is initialized as:

```
string line[0];
```

Comment: You have an array of *zero* `string`s?

Comment: `line = &t;` why? You pass a pointer and then forget about it. What's the point of this argument? perhaps you want to `return t` instead?

Comment: It's probably `*line = t` @Matthieu. Some people like "out arguments" for some reason!

Comment: 1. A zero-size array is not good for anything; 2. assigning a value to a parameter has no effect outside the function.

Comment: Also `t` is a local variable, you can't get a pointer to it and reuse it (even if you pass line as a reference).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed, hence the `return t`. Far better!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `string line[0]` gives you an array of no strings. That's not likely to be what you intended. Why not simply `string line`? That's one string. You'd pass a pointer to that string into your function, with `&line`.

Secondly, `line = &t` replaces the input pointer with a pointer to the local variable. This information is lost once the function ends. If you write `*line = t` then you are instead setting "the string that `line` points to" to the value of "the string `t`".

Ideally you'd avoid the "out argument" and just return the string you want, though.